# Bounded sequence not in $l^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I hope you can help me, I am looking for a real, positive, increasing  and bounded sequence that it is not in $l^2(\mathbb{R})$, where $l^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of real sequences $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2<\infty$.

Is that even possible? Could such a sequence exist?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But this sequence is not increasing

Comment: No increasing sequence of positive numbers is in $\ell^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $a_n=1-\frac  1 n$. Note that $\sum a_n^{2} =\infty$ because $a_n$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: Thank you, this sequence fully satisfies what I was looking for and It is rather simple!

Comment: @IvelF. Then you should accept the answer. Partly to reward Kabo Murphy and partly so that the question no longer appears on the unanswered list.